# How do I prevent a user from deleting the edit row on my datagrid?

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I've got a WPF control with a datagrid bound to an ObservableCollection of objects. The datagrid has CanUsersAddRows set to true so that they can add new elements by typing into the row. However, if the user is typing into the row and and before committing it hits delete, it removes the edit row but never adds another. Has anyone found a way around this?